# How to interpret schoenfield residual plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, survival

I used the veteran database of the package "survival" to do survival analysis. I tried to check the proportional hazard assumption, with with schoenfied residual plot. I always thought if we had a flat line this mean the covariate effect are constant over time, and therfore the proportional hazard assumption were verified. But I see that in these graphs below all lines are flat, although the p.value show the opposite. Finally I wonder how the shoenfield residuals are visually interpreted.

[image]

Comment: You have **very** wide scales on your y-axes, much wider than in base R plots of the `cox.zph` object for this data set/model. The non-flatness is quite evident with base R plotting, which has much more restricted y-axis scales. See Section 3.5.2 of the [survival vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf) for how such plots typically look on these data. The dashed bands (of what type? from which package?) on your plots are far outside almost all the individual residual values, requiring great expansion of the y axes and hiding the details of the curves.

Comment: I've just reproduced your display with current version 0.4.9 of the `survminer` package. For some reason I can't fathom, the author has introduced a multiplicative factor `d` into the y-axis scale of the confidence bands, equal to the number of events! The offending line of code in `ggplotcoxzph`, which is supposed to be a wrapper around `plot.cox.zph`, is `seval <- d * ((pmat %*% xtx) * pmat) %*% rep(1, df)`, where  `d *` is not present in the `plot.cox.zph` code. No wonder you can't see the details.

Comment: This issue has been open and unfixed for 2 years. See https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/444

Comment: thank you for your answers

Comment: This question might ultimately be closed as software-specific and off topic on this site, but thanks for raising it. I now realize that others with questions on this site might have used `survminer` to generate such (fairly useless) plots instead of more standard plotting.

Comment: thank you anyway for your precious explanation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question illustrates both some weaknesses and a strength of using open-source statistical software. These plots were evidently generated by the `ggcoxzph()` function in the R [`survminer` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survminer).

*The main weakness*: a coding problem. Although that function is supposed to be a wrapper around the standard R `survival:::plot.cox.zph()` function to generate `ggplot()` output, the y-axis limits are much broader than those seen in standard plots; see corresponding plots for similar models on this data set in Section 3.5.2 of the R [survival vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf). Those broad limits are needed to include what seem to be displayed as "confidence bands," but they make it impossible to see details of the smoothed line for scaled Schoenfeld residuals versus time.

*The strength*: you can find and fix the coding problem. With open-source R, the code for `ggcoxzph()` and for `survival:::plot.cox.zph()` is open for inspection. The wide "confidence bands" focus attention on how their display might differ between the 2 functions. In the recent survminer_0.4.9 version of `ggcoxzph()`, a critical line of code for calculating those bands differs from `plot.cox.zph()` by a multiplicative factor. The offending line:

```
seval <- d * ((pmat %*% xtx) * pmat) %*% rep(1, df)
```

where `d` is earlier set to the number of events and `d *` is not found in the `survival:::plot.cox.zph()` code. Removing that addition to the code allows plots with reasonable y-axis limits and correct confidence bands.

[image: Fixed ggcoxzph]

*The next weakness*: Even with that fix, it's hard to see details of the shapes of the smoothed curves, as all y axes are compressed to fit plots for all predictors into a single display. That's evidently the default for that function--it's important to question such default settings even if there aren't errors in code. The original `plot.cox.zph()` produces plots for one predictor at a time, which allows for better visualization. Here's the example for `celltype`:

[image: Standard cox.zph plot for "celltype" predictor]

With the physically larger y axis, details of the curve are much more apparent. Remember that those visual curve details depend on another parameter setting, the transformation of the `time` axis chosen in the `cox.zph()` function. The plots shown here are for the default "KM" (Kaplan-Meier) transformation, but there are other options and any function of one argument can be specified.

Code:

```
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
library(survminer)
## survival model and cox.zph
vet1 <-coxph(Surv(time,status)~trt+karno+age+celltype+diagtime+prior,data=veteran)
z1 <- cox.zph(vet1)
## remove d * from ggcoxzph() code, save as function ggcoxzphFixed, not shown
gg1 <- ggcoxzphFixed(z1)
gg1 ## provides plots with correct confidence bands and improved y axes
plot(z1[4]) ## standard plot for the celltype predictor
```